# Predicting species presence with a random forest model based on unbalanced training data

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to build a species distribution model using random-forest:

My training data consists of 971 records of species presence (71)/absence (900) and three environmental variables at systematically sampled points (4*4m, random starting point).

Training data:

```
str(train)
'data.frame':   971 obs. of  4 variables:
$ presence: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ v1     : num  0.18 0.18 0.24 0.24 0.75 0.7 0.27 0 0.29 0.77 ...
$ v2   : num  10 110 19 99 97 71 64 45 54 74 ...
$ v3   : Factor w/ 3 levels "cat1","cat2",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 ...
```

model:

```
model <- randomForest(as.factor(presence) ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = train)
```

My test data (test) consists of 1019 records of the same variables including their coordinates at location B. Additionally I have mapped the species occurrence at location B. So I applied the model on that data:

```
prediction <- predict(model, newdata = test, type="prob")
```

I set `type="prob"`because I wanted to predict the occurrence probability of the species.

The data I generated and want to test against the observed occurrence looks like this:

```
str(prediction_data)
'data.frame':   1019 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ x        : num  180574 180575 180576 180576 180576 ...
 $ y        : num  226954 226953 226951 226953 226955 ...
 $ v1    : num  0.1131 0.5996 0.7187 0.5885 0.0611 ...
 $ v2   : num  10 110 19 99 97 71 64 45 54 74 ...
 $ v3 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ occurrence_prob   : num  0.3252 0.1826 0.0909 0.1014 0.4195 ...
```

Now my doubt is whether it makes sense to consider the unbalanced training data and try to improve the sensitivity of the prediction by using the parameters e.g. `sampsize=(c(71,71)) or classwt = c(0.5, 0.5)`in the model building function when finally I also want to set a probability threshold for classifying the species presence by analyzing the receiver operator curve?!

Would this improve the model sensitivity, be redundant or make things worse?

I would really appreciate any thoughts, advice, opinion, hint. Unfortunately I do not know anyone with whom I could discuss my doubts in person. Thank you!

Comment: Everything depends on your application. It's a balance between specificity and sensitivity and how improving one affects the other. You can try various probability thresholds to classify your data (presense/absence) and then produce a confusion matrix and check false positives and false negatives. For example, classify as "presense" any probability above 0.7 and everything less as "absence" and check your confusion matrix. Then do the same with a 0.8 threshold, etc. Pick the threshold that suits you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are totally right about the trade-offs between sensitivity and  specificity when adjusting the probability threshold. However, my question was whether considering this it makes sense to account for the unbalanced model training data  with a parameter like " classwt = c(0.5, 0.5)" My guess is it does not make sense.